# Why isnt my array code working? php 5 array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this nested array and I need some elements from that array, but for some reason my code isn't working.

When I use `var_dump` i get an array that looks like this

```
array(2) {
     ["item"] => array(1) {
         [0]=> array(3) {
             ["name"]=> string(10) "..."
             ["id"]=> string(16) "..."
             ["rs"]=> string(9) "attending"
          }
      }
     ["id"]=> string(15) "..."
}
```

For example i would like to get id and name, for that I use `foreach`.

```
foreach($var as $key => $value){
    echo $key[0][0]; For name, but that displays nothing
}
```

I also used

```
foreach($var as $key => $value){
    echo $key['item']['name']; Whenever i run this code i get an error "Cannot use string offset etc."
}
```

Yes, i'm aware that this is a dumb question but my head is exploding so please help me guys.

EDIT:

So i'm trying to get 'name' from that array using foreach loop but my code is not working. I don't know how to explain myself better, sorry.

Tried

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value )          
{ 
         echo $array[$key][0]["name"]; 
 }
```

But i'm still getting an error 'Illegal String offset 'name'

Comment: You need to post the code in question as a whole. Also, please add more explanation about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## updated comment

You are indexing the array incorrectly.

This is a proper index for name: echo $array["item"][0]["name"];

A closer solution is:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    echo $array[$key][0]["name"];
}
```

But even that is still wrong.  You'll need to figure out the logic for yourself to continue nesting.  But the crux of your problem is that you're mistaking what the indexes are.

"item" is and index.  0 (the integer 0) is an index.  "name" is an index.

echo $key[0][0]    displays nothing because it's like typing:

"item"[0][0]

And that doesn't reference the array at all.  You need $array for it.

echo $key['item']['name'];  Doesn't work because it doesn't reference the $array variable, and doesn't reference index 0 of the item which actually hosts the information where the "name" exists.

I would need more information about the data you're using to give a full and correct answer.

I suspect a full and complete answer will look similar to one of these two loops:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    if ($key == "item")
    {
        echo $array[$key][0]["name"];
    }
}


foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    if ($key == "item")
    {
        foreach( $array[$key] as $key2 => $value2 )
        echo $array[$key][$key2]["name"];
    }
}
```

`

## Original Comment

I can't comment, was that a typo there?

foreach($var as $key = $value)

Should be

foreach($var as $key => $value)

As per manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: It is still displaying  an error "Illegal string offset name"

Comment: Try using the last foreach loop I wrote for you, in theory it should work, assuming "name" is always there.

Comment: Yeah the last answer solved my problem, thanks man. I actually didnt know before that i need an if statement for that foreach. I thought just using index inside brackets is enough but i guess i'm wrong :D

Comment: Ah, the reason you need the if statement is because for some reason "id" exists in the parent object alongside "item."  

Do me a favor and mark whatever the most appropriate answer was as the answer if you wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has something wrong. Try this:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[$key][0]["name"];
}
```